# TortoiseHg commit complains about non-ASCII characters in the message

Tags: unicode, tortoisehg, non-ascii-characters

The subject tells it all. In 2015, one of the modern VCS doesn't want to accept multilingual commit messages. Though my main development language is English, I need to be able to comment on non-English stuff happening in the software. (I wonder why a program would care to use anything but UTF-8 nowadays, but it's another story.) It says:

[image]

I've found several posts on the web, discussing similar issues, but somehow none of them covers exactly this, nor do I understand how to solve the problem. I have already tried setting the system variable

[image],

but TortoiseHg doesn't seem to notice the difference. On the other hand, I am not sure if I set it correctly.

Comment: Whoever -1-ed this question: it would be great if you explained your position, so I can improve. I am using the default TortoiseHg/Windows/Hg settings, so my problem is likely to be seen by other multilingual software developers. I don't see the reason for the down-vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set `HGENCODING` as a system variable in Windows.  That generally requires a restart to inherit the new environment in all processes.  You may get away with closing and restarting TortoiseHg from the Windows Desktop as Explorer should get a notification that the variable changed and update its own environment.

I could reproduce the issue on my system, but once the variable is set correctly TortoiseHG committed just fine.  Using `HGENCODING=UTF-8` is a valid spelling for that encoding.

Comment: Indeed, rebooting the computer helped. I am not as used to it nowadays any more.

Comment: for me just closing git bash terminal and opening a new one solved it.